# XDocument how to get parent of two nodes, that are not on the same level

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

What is the best approach to get nearest parent of two nodes which are not on the same level in XML document via linq?

Comment: Could you show some code you tried so far and have issues with?

Comment: Get the common ancestor and then work from the common ancestor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple way of finding the nearest common ancestor is to collect all ancestors of the first element into a hash set, and then finding the first ancestor of the second element that is in the set:

```
XElement element1 = ...
XElement element2 = ...
var ancestors = new HashSet<XElement>(element1.Ancestors());
var common = element2.Ancestors().First(a => ancestors.Contains(a));
```

This approach is efficient for a small number of queries on relatively small XML data sets. If the number of queries for the lowest common ancestor is expected to be high, you may need a [more advanced algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lowest_common_ancestor) to solve the LCO problem.